# problema al cargar una template HTML con "fs" nodejs, dentro de una clase ES6

Tags: javascript, nodejs, nodemailer, ecmascript-6

SOLUCIONADO: El problema era que webpack cambia el comportamiento por defecto de __dirname y hay que configurarlo para que las rutas me funcionen.
añadi esto:

```
    context: __dirname,

    node:{
        __dirname: true //The "dirname" of the input file relative to the 
    context option.
    },
```

El problema es el siguiente:

He creado una clase para facilitar el uso de nodemailer con nodejs. Todo me funciona bien, pero al cargar la template con el modulo fs de node, me dice que la ruta no existe. Lo he probado usando simplemente el modulo de node "fs" con el archivo que quiero cargar, en un archivo aparte y me funciona correctamente. Os dejo la clase para ver si me podéis echar una mano.

```
class Mailer {

constructor({ subject }){
    this.emailOptions = {}
    this.emailOptions.subject = subject
    this.emailOptions.from = 'Yo <mi@gmail.com>'
}

/*
* Seteamos el transport por defecto
*/
setAdminTransport(){
    //Configuracion del Transport GMAIL
    let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            type: 'OAuth2',
            user: 'mi@gmail.com',//Email de Gmail
            clientId: key.GMAIL_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: key.GMAIL_CLIENT_SECRET,
            refreshToken: key.GMAIL_REFRESH_TOKEN
        }
    })

    this.transport = transport
    return this
}



/*
* Seteamos la template y sustituimos las variables
* tplName - String
* vars - { }
*/
setTemplate(tpl, variables = ''){

    //Leemos el HTML de la template'verify_email.html'. esta template
    //esta al mismo nivel que la clase Mailer.
    fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'verify_email.html'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        let vars = { name:'Daniella', telefono:'61229333' }

        //sustituir las variables en la template -> {{ variable }}
        for(var key in vars){
            var data = data.replace(`{{${key}}}`, vars[key])
        }

    //Seteamos la template con las variables seteadas
    this.template = data

    })

    return this;
}

getTemplate(){
    return this.template
}


/*
* Un Array con todos los recipients que queremos enviar el email
* recipients - []
*
*/
setRecipients(recipients = []){
    // [ { name: '', address:'' } ]
    this.recipients = recipients
    return this;
}

getRecipients(){
    return this.recipients
}

    /*
* Enviamos el Email por cada recipient
* tplName - String
* vars - { }
*/
send(){
    //Por cada recipient tenemos que enviar un email
    let recipients = this.getRecipients()

        //Por cada Recipient, enviamos un Email
        recipients.forEach(recipient => {
            //seteamos this.emailOptions
            this.emailOptions.to = recipient.address
            this.emailOptions.html = this.template //cargamos la Template HTML

            //enviamos el email
            this.transport.sendMail(this.emailOptions, (err, info) => {
                if (err) throw new Error(err)
                    console.log(`Email enviado a ${this.emailOptions.to} con exito!`)
            })
        })

    this.transport.close()
}

}
export default Mailer
```

Esta clase la llamo desde una ruta asi:

```
router.get('/test', (req, res) => {

let mail = new Mailer({subject: 'Test Nodemailer 2.0'})
  mail.setAdminTransport()
    .setTemplate('verify_email', {name:'Daniella', telefono:'6173333'})
    .setRecipients([ { name: 'Yo', address:'info@myemail.com' } ])
    .send()

res.json({ok:'ok'})
})
```

Este es el error que me da:

```
GET /email/test 200 17.660 ms - 11
[0] { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/verify_email.html'
[0]   errno: -2,
[0]   code: 'ENOENT',
[0]   syscall: 'open',
[0]   path: '/verify_email.html' }
[0] webpack:///./services/mailer.js?:78
[0]                     var data = data.replace('{{' + key + '}}', vars[key]);
[0]                                    ^
[0] 
[0] TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
[0]     at ReadFileContext.eval [as callback] 
(webpack:///./services/mailer.js?:78:21)
[0]     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:336:13)
```

AL CREAR EN UN ARCHIVO APARTE ESTE SCRIPT, ME FUNCIONA PERFECTAMENTE:
el path completo de mi proyecto es:
app/services/mailer/template/verify_email.html
este archivo que me funciona esta en la raiz

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('./services/mailer/template/verify_email.html','utf8',(err, data) => {
if (err) console.log(err);



    var vars = {
        nombre: 'MI NOMBRE',
        telefono: '629648643432'
    }

    for(var key in vars){
        var data = data.replace(`{{${key}}}`, vars[key])
    }

    //ESTO FUNCIONA PERFECTAMENTE Y ME CARGA LA TEMPLATE SUSTITUYENDO LAS VARIABLES
    console.log(data)

})
```

Comment: resolve no esta resolviendo bien la ruta. El resultado es `/verify_email.html` que apunta al directorio raiz. Asegurate que el file este en el lugar indicado, Si estas en una plataforma *nix asegurate que las MAY/min sean iguales.

Comment: la template y la clase estan al mismo nivel, y aun asi, no me la carga poniendo por ejemplo: fs.readFile('verify_email.html', 'utf8'....  ó fs.readFile('./verify_email.html' ...) , alguna idea de por que puede ser? que es lo que tendria que poner?

Comment: prueba de listar el directorio y ver como ve node exactamente el nombre del file. Claramente no lo ve con ese nombre.

Comment: y por que cuando en un script aparte hago lo mismo, si me trae el archivo?  por ejmeplo:  const fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('./services/mailer/template/verify_email.html','utf8',(err, data) => {
 if (err) console.log(err);

 

  var vars = {
   nombre: 'cesar',
   telefono: '629648642'
  }

  for(var key in vars){
   var data = data.replace(`{{${key}}}`, vars[key])
  }

  console.log(data)

}

Comment: Ambos ejemplos que pones en el comentario lo buscan el directorio de trabajo, no necesariamente el que el modulo se encuentra. `node.join(__direname, 'file.html')` es para buscar en el directorio del modulo (similar a resolve y deberia dar el mismo resutlado) .

Comment: cuando pones `__dirname` pides el directoriod donde esta el `.js` ... con `./file.html` o `file.html` lo estas buscando en el directorio de trabajo.

Comment: y entonces como lo harias tu?

Comment: por favor, edita la pregunta y agrega el ejemplo que tienes que si funciona para poder entender mejor donde esta el problema

Comment: no habia visto el comentario donde pones `fs.readFile('./services/mailer/template/verify_email.html','utf8',` ... segun explicaste el file `verify_email.html` esta en la mismca ruta que `Mailer`.. pero en esta ruta parece que la clase `Mailer` esta en el directorio anterior pues le file esta dentro de `template`. En ese caso deberias poner `path.join(__dirname, 'template', 'verify_email.html')` en lugar de lo que tienes ahora o alguna otra forma de incluir el nombre de la carpeta template. salu2

Comment: estas son las rutas de los diferentes archivos:  app/services -> aqui tengo tanto mailer.js (la clase) como el archivo verify_email.html.

Comment: aqui os dejo un enlace a un repo de github donde puedes ver las rutas etc.. a ver si alguien sabe cual es el problema:   https://github.com/cesarcf/readFile

Comment: que version de node estas utilizando ?

Comment: si estas usando webpack y babel faltarian los scripts para armar el bundle.

Comment: (node:v7.5.0) Si, era solo un ejemplo para que vieras las rutas, he probado con: process.cwd() + '/services/verify_email.html' y me funciona, pero no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal con path.join.

Comment: Si lo que pasa es que webpack cambia la forma en que funciona `__dirname` y de ahi viene el problema del codigo que publicaste en la pregunta. El codigo del repo en GH asi como esta no se puede ejecutar, mucho menos debuggear. Salu2

Comment: Chequea esto, https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1599 ahi esta la solicion para usar webpack con `__dirname`

Comment: creo que esta solucionado!! Muchas gracias  @Emanuel Ve ! tienes un amigo en españa!! .  esto es lo que he añadido, en mi configuracion de webpack:   context: __dirname,

  node:{
   __dirname: true //The "dirname" of the input file relative to the context option.
  },

Comment: De nada Cesar!!